# fullPage.js, background and divs not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm trying to change the background of the first section and also include two fullsized divs inside the section. THe background will not show and only half of the other divs will show, everything else is white.

HTML:

```
<div class="section" id="section0">
    <div class="intro">
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <div class="bg hidden"></div>
        <div class="introtext">
            <h1></h1>
            <h2></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
  opacity:0.5;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 5s;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}

.hidden { opacity: 0; margin-top:-50%;}

#section0 {

    background-image:url(img/1.jpg);
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Write if you need any more information, would be forever grateful if anyone could figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position: absolute;` from **.bg** css

Also the browsers do not respect the height in percentage `height: 100%` 
you have to add some content into your div or set the height in pixels by set min-height or max-height for ex: `min-height: 100px;`

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L6ptjyv/6/)

Comment: Didn't seem to work on my end, thanks for the reply though. If you are willing to help me I can send you all the source code.

Comment: The background is working on my side and in the fiddle. How come it didn't work wish you?!

Comment: I think the problem is that there is some trouble with the plugin or any other code on the site. If you would like, I can send you the code so that you can review it.